# How can I iterate through a DataFrame with a conditional to reorganize my data?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in the following format, and I would like to rearrange it based on a conditional using one of the columns of data.

My current DataFrame has the following format:

```
df.head()

Room    Temp1    Temp2    Temp3    Temp4
 R1       1        2        1        3
 R1       2        3        2        4
 R1       3        4        3        5

 R2       1        1        2        2
 R2       2        2        3        3
 ...
 R15      1        1        1        1
```

I would like to 'pivot' this DataFrame to look like this:

```
Room 
 R1 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
 R2 = [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3]
 ...
 R15 = [1, 1, 1, 1,]

 Where:
  R1 = Temp1 + Temp2 + Temp3

 So that:
  R1 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

First: I have tried creating a list of each column using the 'where' conditional in which Room = 'R1'

```
room1 = np.where(df["Room"] == 'R1', df["Temp1"], 0).tolist()
```

It works, but I would need to do this individually for every column, of which there are many more than 4 in my other datasets.

Second: I tried to iterate through them:

```
i = ['Temp1', 'Temp2', 'Temp3', 'Temp4']
room1= []

for i in df[i]:
    for row in df["Room"]:
        while row == "R1":
```

...and this is where I get very lost. Where do I go next? How can I iterate through the rest of the columns and end up with the DataFrame I have above?

Answer (score 1):

This should work (although it's not very efficient and will be slow on a big DataFrame):

```
results = {}  # dict to store results
cols = ['Temp1', 'Temp2', 'Temp3', 'Temp4']
for r in df['Room'].unique():
    room_list = []
    sub_frame = df[df['Room'] == r]
    for col in cols:
        sub_col = sub_frame[col]
        for val in sub_col:
            room_list.append(val)
    results[r] = room_list
```

results will be stored in the result dict, so you can access, say, R1 with:

```
results['R1']
```

Usually iterating over DataFrames is a bad idea though, I'm sure there's a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

The trick is to use the .pivot() function to rearrange the columns accordingly. I had an additonal column called 'Time' which I did not include in the original post thinking it was not relevant to the solution.

What I ended up doing is pivoting the table based on Columns and Values using index as the rooms:

```
df = df.pivot(index = "Room", columns = "Time", values = ["Temp1", "Temp2", "Temp3", "Temp4"]
```

Thank you to those who helped me on the way!